# How to export CSV with multiple columns in Julia

Tags: excel, csv, julia

I could not find the way to export to CSV files with multiple columns in Julia language.

I need to export the results of my model to a csv or excel file. I wanted to find the way to export multiple variables to multiple columns, so that I don´t have to export each variable to a different csv file.

For example you have:

X = [1, 2, 3];
Y = [0, 0, 0, 0];

How can you get X in one column, and Y in another column of the same csv file?

Thank you very much in advance,

Answer (score 4):

I would make an array of empty (or space-filled) strings and then fill with X and Y.

e.g.

```
X = [1, 2, 3]; Y = [0, 0, 0, 0];
out = fill(" ",maximum(length.([X,Y])),2)
out[1:length(X),1] = string.(X); out[1:length(Y),2] = string.(Y)
writecsv("jnk.csv",out)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a `DataFrame` with two columns, and export it to CSV using `writetable` or `CSV.write` (from the CSV.jl package). One of the advantages of this approach over creating an array is that you don't need to copy the column vectors, and that they can be of different types.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.